# write a function that cuts from a list argument passed by reference

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I need to write a function that cuts the first 2 items from the list that is passed as argument and change it. **Not return the modified list**

So if a call:

```
fruits = ['apple','orange','grape','banana']
print fruits # prints ['apple','orange','grape','banana']
f1(fruits)
print fruits # prints ['grape','banana']
```

I tried:

```
def f1(a):
    a[:] = a[2:] # throws TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
def f1(a):
    a = a[2:] # doesn't change the value of fruits
```

Neither `f1(*a)` seems to work. I searched StackOverflow but I can't seem to find an answer.

Please don't tell me to return the value of `a` from `f1`.

Comment: The first function, with `a[:] = a[2:]`, works fine for me.

Comment: Mutable objects are always passed by reference in Python. Your first `f1()` function does not raise a `TypeError` if it is passed a list as an argument (and is a proper way to do what you want). Looks like you must have passed it a single string when testing.

Comment: you're right martineau, but yesterday I tried it with a normal list of strings and it didn't work. strange thing is that now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slice operator ( `[x:y]` ) creates another list, what you have to do instead is to delete the elements that are already in the list like this:

```
def f1(a):
     del a[0:2]
```

Comment: `a[x:y]` may create a new list, but assigning it to `a[:]` replaces `a`'s contents with the new list in place.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below function! You have to mutate `a` itself, not creating another list.

```
def f(a):
    del a[0]
    del a[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pop` method of the list to change input list inplace:

```
def f(a):
   a.pop(0)
   a.pop(0)
```